# Secure WebAPI Call to Non secure Api call fails

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

**Background:**

My Xamarin Forms application is calling Secured WEB API (built-in ASP.Net) to save data, while saving, I need to consume third party API to validate few fields. The third-party API is non secured (without HTTPS).

**The Problem:**

The issue is, my API call to secured API to save data crashes/doesn't complete.

**R&D I tried:**

I hosted ASP.Net Web API on my local server and tried accessing it via Postman (for some reason Xamarin app is not able to communicate with my local server). the call goes through without any problem including communicating with a third-party API to validate data.

Comment: Please add the relevant codes. And do you get some exceptions when the app crash?

Comment: Do you use default httpclient ? Please give us the code, the request headers and exception thrown ?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT - No exception, code will terminate without any error. I could share my code but it does not have any error, it is more like an architecture level.

My Xamarin app calls an API to save data "https://mywebsire/api/SaveMyData", while saving data, "SaveMyData" calls an external API to validate user's Credit card say "http://.api.validatecc" (imaginary).

The problem is "SaveMyData" terminates the execution as soon as it encounters the http call to "http://.api.validatecc" api without any error. 

When I use "http://localhost/api/SaveMyData" (localhost) it works perfectly.

Comment: @Umar3x - Yes I am using httpClient, I an sending Token in the header and nothing more.... please see my comment above for more clear example

Comment: Did you add a try catch to httpRequest SaveMyData?

Comment: Can you use something like fiddler, to check the API return ? Check also your device logcat, there might be something in there

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes I have try catch in SaveMyData

Comment: @Umar3x I did not try fiddler to see what it is returning as my web API terminates the execution. I have no idea about the device logcat, will do some research on it.

Comment: For now, I decoupled the processes, first I am collecting data, then from APP I am getting data validated consuming third party API (http://.api.validatecc"), then second call I am sending it to my SaveData ("mywebsire/api/SaveMyData"). It is working for now but I am not liking two calls for one activity.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your API, while without any exception and errors is hard for us to find out the cause.